# Plotting points - Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am having trouble with plotting the points. I don't know much of python and I am still learning as I go.

Here is my code:

```
def graph(features, labels,classes):
  plt.plot(features[labels[:]==1,0], features[labels[:]==1,1],'g^',
       features[labels[:]==0,0],features[labels[:]==0,1],'rs')
  plt.axis([-4, 4,-4, 4])
  plt.xlabel('x: feature 1')
  plt.ylabel('y: feature 2')
  plt.legend(['Class'+str(classes[1]), 'Class'+str(classes[0])])
  plt.show()


features=np.array([[1,1], [1,0], [0,1], [-1,-1], [0.5,3], [0.7,2], [-1,0], [-1,1], [2,0], [-2,-1]])
labels=np.array([1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1])
classes=[0,1]
```

When I ran the code this is the output:
[Plotting points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXZLg.png)

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `0` in your `features` array so when you do `labels[:]==0` its give you a array of false which is not very usefull.

I think you want to do this at line 3 :

```
features[labels[:]==-1,0],features[labels[:]==-1,1]
```

Here is the result I get doing this :

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def graph(features, labels,classes):
    plt.plot(features[:,0][labels==1], features[:,1][labels==1],'g^')
    plt.plot(features[:,0][labels==-1],features[:,1][labels==-1],'rs')

    plt.axis([-4, 4,-4, 4])
    plt.xlabel('x: feature 1')
    plt.ylabel('y: feature 2')
    plt.legend(['Class'+str(classes[1]), 'Class'+str(classes[0])])
    plt.show()


features=np.array([[1,1], [1,0], [0,1], [-1,-1], [0.5,3], [0.7,2], [-1,0], [-1,1], [2,0], [-2,-1]])
labels=np.array([1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1])
classes=[0,1]

graph(features,labels,classes)
```

which gives:

[image]